# Is it possible for a user to download PDF content displayed on WkWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

We're building an iOS app that displays PDF contents on WkWebView.  PDF contents are only for paid users so we do not want users to download those PDF contents(so they are not spread on internet).

I am wondering if such a thing as downloading PDF contents displayed on WkWebView is possible.  I could not find any info saying it is possible but cannot find any info saying it it NOT possible.

I need solid proof that a user downloading PDF contents from WkWebView is not possible.

Comment: Make sure you take efforts to avoid screen capture as well, then.

Answer (score 0):

WKWebView doesn't expose any methods for accessing the content contained in the WKWebView. (Usually the issue developers have is trying to *allow* users to download content from WKWebViews.)

You can implement Certificate Pinning to prevent someone from using a proxy to intercept the files in-transit.

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to prevent someone from taking a screenshot of the WKWebView. There are libraries (such as [ScreenShieldKit](https://screenshieldkit.com/)) for preventing UI from being captured, but these rely on using special UI components that probably won't work with WKWebView.